# how to use spring 3 mvc to config the way struts does

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-mvc, mapping, forward

I have a controller which returns `ModelAndView("showpage")`, `ModelAndView("forwardToAAA")`, or `ModelAndView("rediretToBBB")`, based on variant conditions. The mapping should be something like this:

```
showpage: showpage.jsp
forwardToAAA: /AAAController.do
redirectToBBB: /BBBController.do
```

I can do this by hard coding it into the controller, such as `forward:/AAAController.do`, and `redirect:/BBBController.do`. But I'd like it to be defined in a configuration file, and let the view resolver to figure it out.

What is the best way to do this in Spring 3 MVC. It can be done easily in struts.

Thanks.

Comment: I think Spring way is much more simplier than Struts one. You are able not only to do redirects to the view with the same name, but forwards by simply adding prefixes!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .properties file loaded somewhere, you can use Spring EL to read a value from it.

For instance, if you had a property named *com.value.url1* in your properties file, you could add this to your Class to pull that value in:

```
@Value("#{ systemProperties['com.value.url1'] }")
private String url1;
```

I am sure there are other ways, like you could have properties in a table and read them in or something, but I think a .properties file is the easiest.